# Scan for MFi devices and display them in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, external-accessory, mfi

I want to scan all the available unpaired MFi devices using External accessory framework and display the devices in a UITableView.

I can use "showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter" like this:

```
var manager = EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager()

func scanForUnpairedDevices() {
    manager.showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter(nil, completion: nil)
}
```

This is the built-in function to scan, display and pair with a MFi device. I don't want the built-in view to be displayed. I just want to scan for the devices and display them in my custom UITableView. Is this possible?

Comment: Note: The MFi device that I want to scan for is a Bluetooth Classic device, not BLE

Comment: @jcaron this will only show accessories that are paired and connected. I do not believe that there is a way to show a list of Bluetooth 2.x EDR devices without using the above API.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Comment removed.

Comment: `manager.connectedAccessories` ?

Comment: manager.connectedAccessories returns devices that are already connected to the phone, I want to scan for unpaired & unconnected devices

Comment: @juppy did u find the solution?

Comment: @Vladislav unfortunately not, I don't think it's possible so I use the built-in view in my app via manager.showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter(nil, completion: nil)

Comment: Hi @juppy , did you managed to solve this issue?